# Impact dropped to almost half, without post being deleted

Tags: bug, profile-page

I just checked my profile page and was wondering quite a bit that my approximate impact dropped from 97k to 55k. How is this possible if none of the posts have been deleted?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is indeed surprising behavior! I just learned about the formula in researching your question. Based on the algorithm at [What happened to the other people? My Impact (people reached) just dropped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251662/307535), namely:

> That's how we got to the current method, which counts views on the following:
>
> **Answers** - Views of the parent question for answers that are:
>
> - Non-deleted AND
> - Score > 0 AND
> - Also meets one or more of the following criteria:
>
>   - In the top 3 answers OR
>   - Is the Accepted Answer OR
>   - Score >= 5 OR
>   - Has at least 20% of the total vote count

I think what happened was that [this answer of yours](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/420286/117549) to a highly-viewed question (41,499 views as of today) fell off the "top 3 answers" list when [this other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/404740/117549) [got an upvote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/404740/timeline) from 1 to 2 on 2019-07-19, taking 3rd place for itself from what was previously a five-way tie for 3rd.  That de-listing of your answer from a ~42k view question seems to account for your "missing" impact numbers.

Comment: thanks for your answer. What is surprising me is that I think I gained my approximate impact rather through my 60 questions then my 15 answers. Also I do not think (but I would need to check this), that any of them is as highly viewed. So for me it rather looked like a change in the way it is calculated. (I think all my posts have < 10000 views). I also wonder about the fact, that the algorithm only explains calculations for answers and not for questions.

Comment: Indeed, questions get a more direct calculation, from what I can see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here) -- simply the number of views on a non-deleted question. Answers get impact counts by virtue of being on a viewed question and meeting the above criteria.